Building Vaadin 24 flow application with java 21 fails to build with version `GLIBC_2.27' not found error
Upgrading my Vaadin flow application to Java 21 is causing the CI/CD build to fail. As far as I can see, the problem occurs when the vaadin-maven-plugin tries to install node:

Spring Boot 3.3.3
java 21 (using maven:3-amazoncorretto-21 to build)
Vaadin 24.0.5

From the logs, it looks like it installs node correctly at this location /root/.vaadin/node/bin/node
Then, it appears as if the plugin verifies the installation by checking the wrong directory (this is just my assumption): version GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /root/.vaadin/node/node)
[INFO] Unpacking /root/.vaadin/node-v18.14.1-linux-x64.tar.gz (43977325 bytes) into /root/.vaadin/node/tmp
[INFO] Copying node binary from /root/.vaadin/node/tmp/node-v18.14.1-linux-x64/bin/node to /root/.vaadin/node/bin/node
[INFO] Extracting npm
[INFO] Local node installation successful.
[WARNING] Error checking if node is new enough
com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendUtils$UnknownVersionException: Unable to detect version of node. Using command /root/.vaadin/node/node --version
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendUtils.getVersion (FrontendUtils.java:843)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendTools.getNodeVersionAndExecutable (FrontendTools.java:673)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendTools.validateNodeAndNpmVersion (FrontendTools.java:628)
    at com.vaadin.flow.plugin.base.BuildFrontendUtil.prepareFrontend (BuildFrontendUtil.java:143)
    at com.vaadin.flow.plugin.maven.PrepareFrontendMojo.execute (PrepareFrontendMojo.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
   
    [...]

Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendUtils$CommandExecutionException: Process execution failed with exit code 1
Output: 
Error output: /root/.vaadin/node/node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /root/.vaadin/node/node)
/root/.vaadin/node/node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /root/.vaadin/node/node)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendUtils.executeCommand (FrontendUtils.java:878)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendUtils.getVersion (FrontendUtils.java:840)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendTools.getNodeVersionAndExecutable (FrontendTools.java:673)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendTools.validateNodeAndNpmVersion (FrontendTools.java:628)
    at com.vaadin.flow.plugin.base.BuildFrontendUtil.prepareFrontend (BuildFrontendUtil.java:143)

   [...]

    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:314)
[ERROR] Command '[/root/.vaadin/node/node, -v]' failed with exit code '1'



Looks like you need update GLIBC library. If not possible upgrade you OS

yes - seems like updating the java image helped fix the issue

It seems like the issue was caused by changing the base and build images when upgrading to Java 21. Using a different build image (maven:3.9.6-eclipse-temurin-21 in my case) solved my problem.
